# C++ code and ArcGIS Button

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c++

I have some code in c++ that used gdal and process raster and create an output raster.
I want to create a button in ArcGIS Desktop (using ArcObjects SDK 10.2 c#) and pass the raster layer to my c++ code (library), break the gdal dependency, and send back the our raster to ArcGIS for display. Is there an example project which I could use for template.

Comment: Not so much, however if you have working GDAL code why not use it? There is a C# lib for GDAL.. I find it much easier to work in GDAL than Esri raster objects (you need about a dozen Esri objects to get the functionality of one GDAL dataset object); is there a specific reason why you need to interface?

Comment: Hi Michael. I want o integrate it with ArcGIS. As the existing code is c++, I have to do a lot of work to shift everything to C# if I decide to use even GDAL for C#. I wanted to have a simple coupling where I can read the Raster data, input to my c++ code, and write it back to a new image. If there is a simple way of integrating c++ with C#, I can try that also. - Masroor

Comment: Have a read of *unsafe* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx it's not quite C++ but in an unsafe block I have copied and pasted small sections of C++; this does not mean that you can use C++ in C# verbatim - it's *unsafe C#* not C++. You still need to use C# objects for rasterio which aren't the same as C++ rasterio and have C# byte arrays... perhaps if there was a bit of code I could offer a bit more help.

Comment: Have you considered trying to just call the C++ function in C# like (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332701/how-to-call-c-dll-in-c-sharp)?  I use this process to do a system parameters check for touchscreen and read back a response.  You should be able to do it for this process, too.

Answer (score 3):

For creating the button, you should look at the following documentation:

https://github.com/Esri/developer-support/tree/master/arcobjects-c++/create-command-atl

As for the other parts, I am unable to find many examples just yet.